# Systemd: Running a script before msyql stops on shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, mysql, upstart

On my `Ubuntu 14` vagrant box I use this `upstart` script to run `automysqlbackup` on every `vagrant halt`:

```
description "run automysqlbackup"
start on stopping mysql
task
exec automysqlbackup
```

So `automysqlbackup` runs just before `mysql` stops.

I'm now using an `Ubuntu 15` box and I have a hard time "translating" this for `systemd`. Do you have any pointers?